# Meaning of *if* in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> For similar reasons fragile natural states cannot support many, if
>   any, private elite organizations.
>
> As the two world wars and the Cold War of the twentieth century
>   illustrate, external violence is a central **if** episodic aspect of the
>   international environment.

What does **if** mean in this context?

Comment: ***If*** there means ***though, albeit, but***. That's to say the writer thinks it's important to point out that the violence is only *episodic*, because otherwise his audience might assume that anything described as *central* would normally be *ever-present, continuous*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, that's good for the second sentence, but the first is a different matter. The first sentence is quite baffling to me, but its usage of *if* is clear enough: the number of private elite organizations that such states can support is small and may well be zero. I can think of no possible substitute for *if* in that context, though.

Comment: @The meaning of "*if any*" is: "*if there are any at all*", or "*(and there might not be any)*".

Comment: @Brian: I obviously paid too much attention to ***this*** in the title, without even registering the fact that it was followed by plural ***sentences***. Since the second example stood out more on the page, I just assumed it was ***this** sentence*. Looking at the first example now, I think you could replace ***if*** with ***or even [not]***. It seems to me the conjunction with ***any*** is something of a "special case" of the commonplace "tentative negation" format in, say, *ELL answers many **if not** most* questions from non-native speakers better than ELU*.

Comment: In the first sentence "if any" is effectively a contraction of "if it can support any" and if is being used In the 2nd conditional sense. In the second sentence "albeit" is probably the best substitute.

Answer (score 1):

*If* is a conjunction which should suggest possibility, but not absolute fact. [Merriam Webster,com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/if) provides definitions, all of which relate to "possible".
Your first example:

> For similar reasons fragile natural states cannot support many, if any, private elite organizations.

*If any* can be written *possibly any*

> For similar reasons fragile natural states cannot support many, possibly any, private elite organizations.

The second example sentence:

> As the two world wars and the Cold War of the twentieth century illustrate, external violence is a central if episodic aspect of the international environment.

may be abusive of the conjunction *if*.
The sentence probably should read:

> As the two world wars and the Cold War of the twentieth century illustrate, external violence is a central,  episodic aspect of the international environment.

In the first statement in the sentence

> As the two world wars and the Cold War of the twentieth century illustrate,

the author establishes the episodic nature of 20th Century violence.
A conjunction might be used:

> As the two world wars and the Cold War of the twentieth century illustrate, external violence is a central *and* episodic aspect of the international environment.

The use of *if* in this sentence probably should be classed as idiomatic. There may be other opinions on this matter; I'd prefer that *if* not confirm facts.